# Unable to check correct radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code here, but i'm unable to check the correct radio button value..

here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/D75JQ/

and here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
var programmerValue = $("#programmer-value input").val();

    $("#btn").on("click", function (){
        alert("ok");
        if (programmerValue == "Yes"){alert(programmerValue)}
        else if (programemrValue == "No"){alert(programmerValue)};
    });
});
```

thanks

Comment: You have typo and your logic is failing, show some effort next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the programmerValue before the user has clicked on the button, you should get it when the user has clicked it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){

    $("#btn").on("click", function (){
        var programmerValue = $("#programmer-value input:checked").val();
        alert("ok");
        if (programmerValue == "Yes"){alert(programmerValue)}
        else if (programmerValue == "No"){alert(programmerValue)};
    });
});
```

You also were not retrieving the checked value of the input, so the first value was taken by default.

Comment: But still need to get the checked one `var programmerValue = $("#programmer-value input:checked").val();` and fix typo `else if (programmerValue == "No")`  http://jsfiddle.net/D75JQ/8/

Comment: Right, will change that

Answer (score 2):

Change to this:

**js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){   
    $("#btn").on("click", function (){
        var programmerValue = $("#programmer-value input:checked").val();
        alert(programmerValue);
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D75JQ/6/)

Comment: Can you explain why OP needs to change it to this?

Comment: He just need to get the value of the checked `radio` and move this `var programmerValue = $("#programmer-value input:checked").val();` into `click` function. Previous he gets the `programmerValue` before the user click the button as @edi9999 mention in his post. Of course don't need to add `if/else` statement cause he already has the value to show.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have the `if` and `else` statement because it will just return whatever is checked and also you need have `:checked` to get the value of the radio button. I also put a validation so if the radio button is not checked it returns `Not checked`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){   
    $("#btn").on("click", function (){
        alert("ok");
        var programmerValue = $("#programmer-value input:checked").val();
        if (!programmerValue) {
        alert("Not checked");
        }
        alert(programmerValue);
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TvBdn/)**

Answer (score -1):

Set programmerValue while clicking the radio button

like

```
$("input").click(function(){
programmerValue = $(this).val();
 });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D75JQ/14/)